# cant select value of jqGrid autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, jquery-autocomplete

I use a jqGrid with jquery autocomplete on one column.

```
{
name : 'mdmKndcode',
index : 'mdmKndcode',
width : 150,
align : "center",
editable : true,
edittype: 'text',
editoptions: {
    dataInit: function(elem) {
        var cache = {};
        $(elem).autocomplete({
            source:  function( request, response ) {
                var term = request.term;
                console.log(term);
                if(term in cache){
                    response(cache[term]);
                    return
                }
                $.getJSON( "/example/json/"+term, request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                    cache[ term ] = data;
                    response( data );
                  });
                },

            minLength:3
        }); 
    }
}
```

In the grid I can see the results of json request in autocomplete list. This works fine. But  I am not able to select a value in this list. The autocomplete list getting closed and lose the focus of the column after a mouseover or Keyboard press on the list.

Tried also with "select" function but same result.

Want to have the selection of the values in the list like in this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/27dLM/38/)

Comment: post similar jsfiddle here but with code that doesn't work

Comment: I wrote a simple function. But this shows exactly the problem in the Grid. (also in the example). [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FMKwC/2/) Maybe i missed some external js/css files?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your jsfiddle, the problem is that you are including jqueryui twice `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui-custom.min.js` , most likely both of them have autocomplete and that causes troubles.
Remove one of them and that will fix the issue.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/B36gf/)